# apply_strategies() on database can't find a migration that is present in the folders

Tags: brightway

I want to work on ecoinvent 3.3 cutoff database with brightway, so I did:

```
from brightway2 import *
fp = *somefilepath*
ei = SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(fp, "ecoinvent 3.3 cutoff")
ei.apply_strategies()
```

When executing the last line, I get the following error: Can't find migration fix-ecoinvent-flows-pre-34

The problem is that the migration IS in the folder C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\envs\my_env\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\data\lci and is called ecoinvent_pre34_migration.json

Does anyone know why it's not working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ecoinvent_pre34_migration.json file *is* there, and you are getting a `Can't find migration` error, then you need to re-add your core migrations data files:

```
from bw2io.migrations import create_core_migrations
create_core_migrations()
```

should do the trick.